# Using Google's maps sdk android utility library in Huawei Map Kit

Tags: android, google-maps, huawei-mobile-services, cluster-manager, huawei-map-kit

I am trying to migrate Google Maps to Huawei Map kit. But there are no features for ClusterManager, ClusterItem, DefaultClusterRenderer e.t.c.

Now I am trying to use below [this library](https://github.com/billtom20/3rd-maps-utils) for it:

But I do not know how to implement it. I opened Gradle window and expand Tasks under my project then double-clicked assemble but it did not extract that .aar file and gave me below error:

[image]

How to solve this? How to implement this library? Anyone here to implemented this successfully?

```
dependencies {
   implementation(name: '3rd-maps-utils-2.2.0-yyyyMMdd', ext: 'aar')
...
}
```

Comment: Try this lib: https://github.com/SupasinTatiyanupanwong/huawei-maps-utils For me it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

1.You need refer [Github](https://github.com/billtom20/3rd-maps-utils) to download the code.

2.Run the code, click library->Tasks->build->assemble.

3.After Run, find 3rd-maps-utils-2.1.0-yyyyMMdd.aar file in
library/build/outputs/aar/ path.

4.Copy 3rd-maps-utils-2.1.0-yyyyMMdd.aar file to your own app/libs/ path.

5.Add codes below in project build.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
       repositories {
              ...
              flatDir {
                     dirs 'libs'
              }
       }
}
```

6.Add codes below in app build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation(name: '3rd-maps-utils-2.1.0-yyyyMMdd', ext: 'aar')
    ...
}
```

---

You can refer this screenshoot where you can find the assemble in the upper right corner of AS by clicking "Gradle" :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer again. I already did it and got an error. I  updated my question now. Please, take a look

Comment: I updated my answer,pls kindly refer, I hope it is clear to explain like this :)

Comment: Thank you I got it. I downloaded the project from gitlab but could not build it. Getting the below error:

3rd-maps-utils-main\demo\build.gradle' line: 67

A problem occurred evaluating project ':demo'.
> Plugin with id 'com.huawei.agconnect' not found.

Comment: Before run this demo, you need to Creating an App in AppGallery Connect to configure the project,please kindly refer this [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSPreparation/index.html#0)